# jQuery Validation: How to not display errors? OR How to display errors as a tooltip?

Tags: jquery, validation

I want my errors to float above, left-justified, the input field that doesn't validate.  How can I do this?

If I can't, how can I turn the errors off?  I still want the fields to validate (and highlight on error), but not for the actual error messages to display.  I couldn't seem to find anything in the jQuery docs that would let me turn them on/off... ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want the errorPlacement option, and perhaps errorContainer and errorElement for further customization.

See http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Answer (score 14):

Use the errorPlacement property for your jQuery validation call, as J Cooper suggested:

```
$(...).validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertBefore(element);
    }
});
```

And CSS to style the error (in your stylesheet, or to the individual elements):

```
label.error {
    /* Move the error above the input element. */
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin-top: -1.5em;

    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 2px;
}
```

Comment: For the jQuery bit: should use insertBefore() instead of before().  Thanks!