# How do you display a validation balloon using JavaScript and ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net

I use asp.net page and in that page use validation. How to show Message in balloon

Exp: User Name_________
IT use only alpha bate  a-z or A-Z

display Message using balloon like "Please enter valid char only"

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript to validate the input and display a message if it is invalid.  You could use a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) [UI](http://jqueryui.com/) [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) for the balloon.

Answer (score 0):

This post could be really helpful for ya:
[jQuery override default validation error message display (Css) Popup/Tooltip like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860055/jquery-override-default-validation-error-message-display-css-popup-tooltip-like)