# jquery validation plugin won't show error again

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

i am using jquery validation plugin for form validation. The problem is this, that when i use **errorPlacement** and **success** opption in validate, my error doesn't appear again after once validate, if i comment **errorPlacement** and **success** and run the script again it work fine.

```
$('#registrationForm').validate({
    rules : {},
    messages : {},
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    var container = $('<div />');
    container.addClass('Ntooltip');  // add a class to the wrapper
    error.insertAfter(element);
    error.wrap(container);
    $("<div class='errorImage'></div>").insertAfter(error);
    },

    success: function(element) {
        $(element).addClass("checked");
    }
});
```

But if i use **errorPlacement** and **success** in my validation script, then submit my form it work fine at once, all error were show up, after that if i insert valid input then  my error  hide and showed this is a valid input. **Problem: after insert valid input i again change my valid input to invalid it doesnot show error again**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found my answer this article  [jquery validation errorPlacement issue when adding tooltip style error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876872/jquery-validation-errorplacement-issue-when-adding-tooltip-style-error-message) , I didn't find that time so i post my Question.

```
showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
            for (var i = 0; errorList[i]; i++) {
                var element = this.errorList[i].element;
                this.errorsFor(element).remove();
            }
            this.defaultShowErrors();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up [debug mode](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) to see what's happening internally...

```
$('#registrationForm').validate({
    debug: true,
    rules : {},
    messages : {},
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    var container = $('<div />');
    container.addClass('Ntooltip');  // add a class to the wrapper
    error.insertAfter(element);
    error.wrap(container);
    $("<div class='errorImage'></div>").insertAfter(error);
    },

    success: function(element) {
        $(element).addClass("checked");
    }
});
```

Comment: i found my answer in other article. I try to find answer that time but at that i didn't find so i post my Question. But now i get my answer. Thanks for your concern.