# How to put form labels on the right?

Tags: jquery

Please look at the following comment form:
[http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

I'd like to put the labels on the right of text input fields and display the error messages under input fields.
Tried almost anything, but to no avail. :-(

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Rain Lover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [error placement](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) option of jquery validate plugin.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860055/jquery-override-default-validation-error-message-display-css-popup-tooltip-like) SO question covering a similar question.

Comment: More than what I expected -- So helpful! Thanks! :-)