# styling jquery validation error text

Tags: jquery-validate, styling, custom-errors

I'm using [jquery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and would like customize the error messages that are displayed.

By default the validation errors appear to the right the input fields.  I specifically would like to have all the errors to appear at the top of the page in a styled div we have been using.

Is this possible with library or would it be a better option to just write my own validation stuff this situation?

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: This [post][1] will totally help you out


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860055/jquery-override-default-validation-error-message-display-css-popup-tooltip-like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Ray
I'm sure you've found it by now but if not, this can be done using the `errorLabelContainer` option. See [jquery.validation docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).

e.g.

```
$("#myform").validate({
  errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox"
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Rich.  Yeah, not a lot of exposure... only 12 views.